# How to prove that a given language is not regular?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $L$ be the set of all words over $\{a,b\}$ in which the number of $b$'s are exactly double of $a$'s. How can one show that $L$ is not a regular language?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Are you familiar with any techniques, such as pumping lemmas or myhill-nerode? Is this for a class, or are you self-teaching? The more we know about your situation, the better we can help you ^_^

Comment: I fully subscribe to HallaSurvivor's comment. What do you know already about regular and non-regular languages?

Comment: The question title is misleading as it contains a double negation, while you want to *prove non-regularity“

Comment: @PrudiiArca I edited the title so it wouldn't be misleading.

Comment: If the pumping lemma is available, then it seems to give the easiest proof. If you don't yet have the pumping lemma, then it's important (as others have said) to tell us what is available. For example, which of the equivalent definiitons of "regular language" are you using? If "regular" means "recognized by a deterministic finite automaton" then there's an easy proof; other definitions of "regular" may need more work.